# codeigniter form post from a folder inside controller not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, here is my problem.

In codeigniter, I have a folder inside controllers named admin and the controller admin.php inside that.
The problem is when i try posting a form from this controller to a controller outside admin folder, it does'nt works. I m really getting frustated trying to figure out where exactly i am doing wrong.

my routes.php is-

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/$1";

$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

and my base url is `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_extend/';`

Actually the form is getting posted to self.
I know, surely there is routing problem but just cant figure it out. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have your controller in your admin folder named admin.php
you should route it as below

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/admin/index/$1";
```

I've included function name i.e. `index` , I guess the function name is required, give a hit without function name if you want to, but I don't see any problem in keeping it.

**Accepted Answer**

Change `$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/$1";` > `$route['welcome/(:any)'] = "welcome/$1";` & if using `<form>` make sure `CSRF` either disabled or you included CSRF token in the form

Comment: its not working too, Actually the form is getting posted to self.

Comment: you using `form_open('admin');` ?

Comment: no. its <form  action="<?php echo site_url('welcome/newest'); ?>" method="post">

Comment: Change `$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/$1";` > `$route['welcome/(:any)'] = "welcome/$1";` & if using <form> make sure CSRF either disabled or you included CSRF token in the form

Comment: Thanks, it worked! you should edit your answer so that i can accept it. thanks again! :)